# Something wrong with Tomcat favicon

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, favicon

I've got a problem with running my projects in STS(eclipse). I use Tomcat 7. All the time i run projects over **run as - run on server**. And always I getting in the upper left corner icon of Tomcat.
But now i tried to run over the **maven build - tomcat7:run** 
Here i just added in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And now when i write localhost:8080/app, I getting in the upper left corner icon red "J:" - type Jetty. Even if i do **run as-run on server**. And already in the browser if I write localhost:8080, main page Tomcat does not open, gives an error. How to fix it?How to retrieve Tomcat icon when i browse my projects after run server?

Comment: Please post your screens / logs etc?

Comment: Can you show the configuration..?

Comment: configuration of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And already in the browser if I write localhost:8080, main page Tomcat does not open, gives an error. How to fix it?

Looks like a configuration mismatch ( I won't count it as an issue ) . To resolve this, Goto *server tab* --> double click on the particular tomcat server --> *Server Loaction* --> Select *Use tomcat installation ( take control of tomcat installation)*. Then re-start your server and you should be able to see the tomcat home page at `http://localhost:8080` again.